# Change name to Strapi plugin

Tags: strapi

Guys I need to change Strapi v4.10.5 plugin name and move it above Content manager if possible ... any ideas or experience? I am working on this task several hours, tried plenty of things but all of them are deprecated, any ideas or experience?